# Thickbox title showing up twice

Tags: jquery, thickbox

I have a link that opens a Thickbox...

```
<a href="page.php?tag=lists-element&keepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=450&width=500">
```

Everything works with this except when the Thickbox opens up the title is displayed twice:

[image]

Any ideas as to why this is happening or how it can be fixed?

Comment: quite hard to decipher your problem with the info you provided. Do you have a live url we can look at?

Comment: Unfortunately no...
I am using the most current Thickbox and jQuery.  

This works for me properly, but it's for inline content only.
#TB_inline?height=600&width=800&inlineId=searchDiv&modal=false

I was thinking it was something to do with the formatting of my href=""  Is there any specific details I can post to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that makes sense to me is that either something on the "page.php" opens another Thickbox, or that the "page.php" itself contains the extra title.

Since you're not doing anything out of the ordinary with the Thickbox class, I doubt that it is a bug in the actual script.

To debug this, I would first remove the "tag=lists-element" from the query string of the URL, as I don't think that is a Thickbox option (correct me if I'm wrong). That way you can strip it down to the basics and test from there.

Comment: You are correct on the tag=...that has to do with my script.  I took that out and still no luck but I'm still looking to what might be going on.  I think it has something to do with the frames.  I did just notice that thickbox is no longer supported.  Maybe it's time to move to jQueryUI's dialog.?.

Comment: I've always used Colorbox (http://colorpowered.com/colorbox). You should definitely check it out -- it's SO easy to use and very powerful/customizable.

Answer (score 2):

`thickbox.js` and `thickbox.css` are included twice in your page. That's why this problem occurred. Remove this duplication  and your problem will solved.

Alternatively, you may be including `thickbox.js` and `thickbox_compressed.js` or `thickbox_min.js`.

Answer (score 1):

i was getting the same error i was using the below code

```
if (Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().get_isInAsyncPostBack()) 
       {
            tb_init("a.thickbox, area.thickbox, input.thickbox");
       }
```

in my master page i commented it it started working fine

Answer (score 1):

In my JQuery script which was added to the page.

I put in:

```
tb_init("a.thickbox, area.thickbox, input.thickbox");
```

sorry to say, 4 times in if statements.
Like so:

```
    if ($(".ToDoList:contains('Times - Incomplete')").length != 1
        & $(this).val().length > 2) {
        $(".ToDoList ul").append('<li><a title="Disposition" class="thickbox1"><span>Times - Incomplete</span></a></li>');
        //tb_init('a.thickbox, area.thickbox, input.thickbox');
        $(".contentRightHand").show();
    }
```

This was early on in development which at the time seemed like the solution to the problem.
Now I went back and removed them, everything still works.
So obviously, it was not needed in the first place.

But, that's what was causing the problem I had.

Answer (score 0):

In Master Page I added `thickbox-compressed.js` and in normal aspx page also I added the `thickbox-compressed.js.

Because of these double addition of references its showing twice so please remove these duplicate references.